# Do physical disabilities carry over into the Matrix? (And vice versa)

Tags: the-matrix

So, I'm writing this fanfiction for the Matrix and my main character is physically disabled. More specifically, her physical pod body was born blind.

Would she then be blind in the Matrix, or would she have sight because of the whole jack/port in the skull thing?

And what about the reverse? Could someone have like a lost limb from being in say, a car accident in the Matrix, and then when they're unplugged their physical body is perfectly fine?

Comment: That said, the specifics on why she is blind (Eye/Nerve damage vs Brain damage) also matters. If someone does not have a working Visual Cortex, short of the brain developing a secondary center to process that information, I have no idea how the matrix would handle it. It could make them blind in the matrix, or might recycle the body for nutrients. There could be people who have no physical handicaps in the pod, but were assigned a random disability in the matrix, and people with physical handicaps that are given normal lives. There is a lot of room to play around with it.

Comment: Which also begs the question, are people who contract a disease or sickness in the matrix, really sick? No physical contact, no stds, contagious rashes, no airborne virus. But physical conditions like Cataracts or Psoriasis or Osteoporosis shouldn't translate to the matrix either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The avatars, for a lack of a better word, in the Matrix, are mental self-projections of the person. Notice Neo, once removed from the Matrix for the first time, is hairless, pale, scrawny, has atrophied muscles and is completely sensitive to normal room lighting because his muscles and eyes have never been used. In real life, a 20+ year coma would require months of physical therapy to get back to moving around, unlike Neo who only needed a few days/weeks based on how the movie progresses. His vocal chords, sense of smell, even lungs would have been weak (depending on how the pods actually keep the humans viable).

But once he got jacked into the training simulation, and later, the Matrix, as Morpheus explains:

> "Your appearance now is what we call residual self-image. It is the mental projection of your digital self."
>   ―Morpheus to Neo

The avatar conforms to how the user wants to look, or believes they should look. Digital muscles, clothing, hair cuts, etc. Morpheus is physically stronger than Neo, and has had full use of his physical body for years, while Neo is weak from muscle atrophy.

> Morpheus: How did I beat you?
>   Neo: You’re too fast.
>   Morpheus: Do you believe that my being stronger or faster has anything to do **with my muscles in *this place***? You think that's air you're breathing now? *A Beat* Hah. Again.
>   -Training Simulation Scene

Yet after Neo stops thinking of physical limitations in the Matrix, he's as fast and as strong as Morpheus. There are limits to what they can look like imposed by the Matrix of course, basic humanoid, but as everything else in the Matrix, those rules can be bent and sometimes broken.

In real life, physical ability to do something is mutually exclusive to a person's mental self. Phantom limb sensation and phantom pain are common in people who have lost any limb or part of the body. The CNS and PNS still think the limb is there.

But the Matrix does have limitations, which might be a technological limitation OR imposed to maintain order. If a person dies in the Matrix, they die in real life.

It’s speculation on my part, but I think physical trauma in the Matrix can cause Conversion Disorders like paralysis in the real world, the inability to move your muscles but only due to a mental block. It would be treated through typical therapy. The same would apply to physical trauma in the real world being part of the Residual Self Image in the Matrix. The user would have to work around their mental belief of disability just like Neo worked around his belief that he couldn't jump across buildings.

Comment: The Animatrix episode [World Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Animatrix#.22World_Record.22) shows that exceptional people are capable of overcoming physical disability in the Matrix. Also, Neo was blinded in the real world but was still able to see in the Matrix.

Comment: @xantec i didnt mention both of those because World Record is an example of rule bending, like all users can do, and Neo, as the one, could see machine code and the source through a six sense. After he is blinded, we are never shown if he has normal vision or not. But we already know he has machine code vision at the end of the first movie. So Neo is an outlier that cant be counted.

Answer (score 1):

Your character would be able to see perfectly well inside the Matrix.

After being blinded, Neo doesn't need to be able to *physically see* in order to use his virtual eyes. Someone who was blind from birth (due to a [defect](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3119278/) in their eyes) would simply have had vision simulated for them using another part of their brain.

With regard to more dramatic disabilities such as missing limbs, on several occasions (both within the film and Comic canon) we see that the [Residual Self-Image](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Residual_self_image) can be manipulated. Trinity shifts her clothing between scenes and in "Burning Hope", the titular character projects an RSI that is dramatically different to her real out-of-matrix self.

Unless the character had a good reason for simulating a missing limb, there's no reason to presume their in-Matrix character would display such a disability.

[image]

[image]

Out-of-universe, the character of Switch was [allegedly](http://www.omgfacts.com/Celebs/The-character-Switch-in-The-Matrix-was-t/52909) going to be female inside the Matrix and male outside, played by two similar-looking characters. This strongly suggests that any missing parts (ahem) would simply be hand-waved aside by the concept of RSI.